# AI GENERATED MODEL USE FOR FASHION INDUSTRY

Tags: halal-haram, hijab, work, technology, religion

Hope this message finds you safe and well.

I am planning to start a jewellery business. I'd jewellery photographed. Particularly on women, which I know would not be appropriate. Hence I am thinking to get AI generated female model photos (not with revealing clothing) but neck and ears visible to manually edit jewellery to advertise. Would this also be haram or no? As there wont be any actual woman being exposed to non-mehram